# I'm getting TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object "

Tags: python, nltk

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

paragraph = ''' State-run Bharat Sanchar Nigam Ltd (BSNL) is readying to pay November salary in another two days, which will be raised from internal accruals and bank loans.'''  

sentence = nltk.sent_tokenize(paragraph)
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
    words = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in words if word not in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    sentence[i] = ' '.join(words)
```

I am getting an error on this part

```
words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
```

Comment: it's should be `words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence[i])` ?

Comment: what exactly sentence[i] does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range()` produces an iterable of integers. So, when you feed `i` into `nltk.word_tokenize()`, you're feeding it an integer. Obviously, an integer is not string-like.

I don't personally know how `nltk.word_tokenize()` is supposed to work, but based on context clues it would seem you might want to pass the sentence object *at the index `i`* instead of just the index `i`:

```
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence[i])
```